# Way to toggle debugging code on and off

Tags: c++, debugging

I was programming a manchester decoding algorithm for arduino, and I often had to print debug stuff when trying to get things working, but printing to serial and string constants add a lot of overhead. I can't just leave it there in the final binary.

I usually just go through the code removing anything debug related lines.
I'm looking for a way to easily turn it on and off.

The only way I know is this

```
 #if VERBOSE==1
     Serial.println();
     Serial.print(s);
     Serial.print(" ");
     Serial.print(t);
     Serial.print(" preamble");  
 #endif

...

 #if VERBOSE==1
     Serial.println(" SYNC!\n");
 #endif
```

and on top of the file I can just have

```
#define VERBOSE 0 // 1 to debug
```

---

I don't like how much clutter it adds to single liners. I was very tempted to do something very nasty like this. But yeah, evil.

Change every debug output to

```
verbose("debug message");
```

then use

```
#define verbose(x) Serial.print(x) //debug on
```

or

```
#define verbose(x) //debug off
```

---

There's a C++ feature that allows me to just do this instead of preprocessor?

Comment: I happen to like your "very nasty" idea and would do it in a heartbeat.

Comment: Your "very nasty" method has been the standard for decades.  But don't just `#define verbose(x)` for the OFF case, instead use `#define verbose(x) {;}`.  That way code like `if (badThingHappend) verbose('OMG!')` doesn't accidentally capture the next statement.

Comment: Yes, this is hugely common, though generally the define is called `DEBUG`.

Answer (score 9):

At the risk of sounding silly: Yes, there is a C++ feature for this, it looks like this:

```
if (DEBUG)
  {
     // Your debugging stuff here…
  }
```

If `DEBUG` is a compile-time constant (I think using a macro is reasonable but not required in this case), the compiler will almost certainly generate no code (not even a branch) for the debugging stuff if `debug` is false at compile-time.

In my code, I like having several debugging levels.  Then I can write things like this:

```
if (DEBUG_LEVEL >= DEBUG_LEVEL_FINE)
  {
     // Your debugging stuff here…
  }
```

Again, the compiler will optimize away the entire construct if the condition is false at compile-time.

You can even get more fancy by allowing a two-fold debugging level.  A maximum level enabled at compile-time and the actual level used at run-time.

```
if (MAX_DEBUG >= DEBUG_LEVEL_FINE && Config.getDebugLevel() >= DEBUG_LEVEL_FINE)
  {
     // Your debugging stuff here…
  }
```

You can `#define MAX_DEBUG` to the highest level you want to be able to select at run-time.  In an all-performance build,  you can `#define MAX_DEBUG 0` which will make the condition always false and not generate any code at all.  (Of course, you cannot select debugging at run-time in this case.)

However, if squeezing out the last instruction is not the most important issue and all your debugging code does is some logging, then the usual pattern lokks like this:

```
class Logger
{
public:

  enum class LoggingLevel { ERROR, WARNING, INFO, … };

  void logError(const std::string&) const;
  void logWarning(const std::string&) const;
  void logInfo(const std::string&) const;
  // …

private:

  LoggingLevel level_;
};
```

The various functions then compare the current logging level to the level indicated by the function name and if it is less, immediately return.  Except in tight loops, this will probably be the most convenient solution.

And finally, we can combine both worlds by providing `inline` wrappers for the `Logger` class.

```
class Logger
{
public:

  enum class LoggingLevel { ERROR, WARNING, INFO, … };

  void
  logError(const char *const msg) const
  {
    if (COMPILE_TIME_LOGGING_LEVEL >= LoggingLevel::ERROR)
      this->log_(LoggingLevel::ERROR, msg);
  }

  void
  logError(const std::string& msg) const
  {
    if (COMPILE_TIME_LOGGING_LEVEL >= LoggingLevel::ERROR)
      this->log_(LoggingLevel::ERROR, msg.c_str());
  }

  // …

private:

  LoggingLevel level_;

  void
  log_(LoggingLevel, const char *) const;
};
```

As long as evaluating the function arguments for your `Logger::logError` etc calls does not have visible side-effects, chances are good that the compiler will eliminate the call if the conditional in the `inline` function is false.  This is why I have added the overloads that take a raw C-string to optimize the frequent case where the function is called with a string literal.  Look at the assembly to be sure.

Comment: One advantage to using the if (CONDITION) method, is if CONDITION evaluates to zero, the syntax is still checked between the { } pair (or at least it is with my PIC32 compiler) -- where it is not if one uses the #ifdef CONDITION method.

Comment: @tcrosley Yes, that's the main advantage, imho, and that is also why [the GNU coding standards](https://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/html_node/Conditional-Compilation.html#Conditional-Compilation), for example, favor this style over preprocessor trickery.

Answer (score 3):

Personally I wouldn't have a a lot of `#ifdef DEBUG` scattered around my code:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
   printf("something");
#endif
  // some code ...
#ifdef DEBUG
   printf("something else");
#endif
```

rather, I would wrap it in a function:

```
void DebugPrint(const char const *debugText)  // ToDo: make it variadic [1]
{
#ifdef DEBUG
  printf(debugText);
#endif
}

DebugPrint("something");
// some code ...
DebugPrint("something else");
```

If you don't define `DEBUG` then the macro preprocessor (not the compiler) won't expand that code.

The slight downside of my approach is that, although it makes your cod cleaner, it imposes an extra function call, even if `DEBUG` is not defined. It is possible that a smart linker will realize that the called function is empty and will remove the function calls, but I wouldn't bank on it.

References:

1. [“Variadic function” in: Wikipedia, The Free Encyclopedia.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function)

Comment: One danger with using a function is that arguments will get evaluated even in "release" mode.  For instance, `DebugPrint(FormatErrorString(arg1,arg2,arg3))`.  This can slow things down.  By making `DebugPrint` a macro, this won't happen because any code that generates arguments is removed completely.

Comment: @StevenBurnap: It is possible to perform a runtime boolean check before starting to process the variadic arguments. This requires the use of `va_list` and `vsprintf`. The user also needs to understand that `FormatErrorString` would return nothing if debug message is disabled.

Comment: It's the second part that is the issue.  It means you have to instrument `FormatErrorString` with `#ifdef DEBUG`.  It also means that `FormatErrorString` can't be something that non-debug tools use.  I experienced a fairly painful issue with performance that was caused by exactly this.

Answer (score 3):

I also would suggest to use inline functions which become empty if a flag is **set**. Why when it is set? Because you usually want to debug always unless you compile a release build.

Because `NDEBUG` is already used you could use it too to avoid using multiple different flags. The definition of a debug level is also very useful.

One more thing to say: Be careful using functions which are altered by using macros! You could easily violate the [One Definition Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule) by translating some parts of your code with and some other without debugging disabled.

Answer (score 0):

You might follow the convention of [assert(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/assert.3.html) and wrap debugging code with

```
 #ifndef NDEBUG
 DebugPrint("something");
 #endif
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9239084/841108) (on StackOverflow, which would be a better place to ask) for a practical example.

In a more C++ like style, you could consider

```
ifdef NDEBUG
#define debugout(Out) do{} while(0)
#else
extern bool dodebug;
#define debugout(Out) do {if (dodebug) {                 \
  std::cout << __FILE__ << ":" << __LINE__ \
  << " " << Out << std::endl; \
 }} while(0)
#endif
```

then use `debugout("here x=" << x)` in your program. YMMV. (you'll set your `dodebug` flag either thru a `gdb` command or thru some program argument, perhaps parsed using [getopt_long(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getopt_long.3.html), at least on Linux).

PS. Remind that the `do{`...`}while(0)` is an [old trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/154138/841108) to make a robust statement like macro (suitable in every position where a plain statement is, e.g. as the then or else part of an `if` etc...).

Comment: Don't you think that a macro definition and a variable are a bit overkill? Also - why are you using a do while loop if you end it anyways?

Comment: No, not at all. And if you want to have the file & line information it is nearly mandatory.

Comment: Ah, okay, thanks for the explanation. That seems reasonably. Although I still think that macros which look like functions and are used like functions are errorprone and dangerous.

Comment: These are *debugging* macros for *developers*. And these are not that dangerous (no more sideeffects that what is expectable), exactly in the spirit of `assert`

Comment: Okay. You are right. I was simply scared of the fact that you cannot simply distinguish between them and normal functions. I am not a fan of them and I try to avoid them when possible.

Comment: BTW, your (or the OP) approach of a *long* sequence of instructions wrapped in `#ifdef` is more error prone. Once could more easily add some side-effect (e.g. an increment) inside them while forgotting that is debugging code!

Comment: Not my approach. My approach is the one which has the potential to violate the one definition rule when not used with caution. :D

Answer (score 0):

You could also use templates utilizing the `constexpr if` feature in C++17. you don't have to worry about the preprocessor at all but your declaration and definition have to be in the same place when using templates.